# Returning only the first child in a child node

Tags: rabl

I have a story model and a post model.  Each story has many posts.

In my story#index action I would like to use rabl to return all @stories, and each story in @stories should also include a child node containing attributes from its most recently created post.

Here is the closest that I've come to achieving what I'm looking for:

```
#show.json.rabl

object @story

attributes  :id, :title, :username

child @story.posts.first => :latest_post do
  attributes  :id, :story_id, :contents, :username
end
```

This works fine in the stories#show action.  But when I try to extend it with the stories#index action

```
#index.json.rabl

collection @stories

extends "stories/show"
```

I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass):
    1: collection @stories
    2: 
    3: extends "stories/show"
  app/views/stories/show.json.rabl:8:in `render'
```

I believe that I get this error because I'm not setting the @story instance variable used by the show.json.rabl view.  But I'm not sure how to get around this and pass the show.json.rabl the correct story object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a rabl partial to solve the problem.  Here's how:

```
#story.show.json.rabl

object @story

attributes  :id, :title, :username

node :latest_post do |story|
  { :post => partial("posts/show", :object => story.posts.first)}
end
```

---

```
#story.index.json.rabl

collection @stories

extends "stories/show"
```

---

```
post.show.json.rabl

object @post

attributes  :id, :story_id, :contents, :username
```

This works exactly as required.